# Copying a PS Get-Date output to Clipboard

Tags: date, syntax, command-line-arguments, clipboard, powershell-5.1

I'd appreciate some expert input on what errors I have made below :)

I need to:

1. Copy a PowerShell command string into the Windows Search Bar
2. Obtain the current system date
3. Obtain from the current system date, the date 3 months in the past
4. Format this past date like so: DD.MM.YYYY
5. Copy this formatted date to the clipboard
6. Terminate the PowerShell window

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2.
I do not have Administrator rights in this environment.

PSVersion 5.1.19041.3031
PSEdition Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion 10.0.19041.3031
CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1

Thank-you in advance.

I have been attempting to use the following command, however am unable to get a usable output.

cmd /c "powershell -NoProfile Get-Date.adddays(-90) -format ^"{yyyy-MM-dd}^"|clip"